# Updating scope in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

According to several sources, using $parent to update a scope from within ng-repeat (because it has its own scope) is discouraged. I do the following to update the data model from within ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="datarow in datasource">
   <select ng-model="datasource[$index].property" ng-options="option.first_name for option in datarow.options"></select>
</div>
```

I use `datasource[$index].property` to update the datasource array. This way I can see when a user has made choice in all the dropdowns and I can enable the button to submit a form.

Is there a better way to do this? I'd rather not use $parent.

Comment: You can at least change the ng-model to `<select ng-model="datarow.property" ... ></select>`

Comment: When I do that, the object in the datasource array doesn't get modified in my controller's scope.

Comment: It should be modifying it on the scope since it is the same object.  Perhaps if you are trying to detect when the user has made a choice in all dropdowns, you should use ng-change in each select.  Or look into [forms](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:form) and enable the button when the form is valid.

Comment: Hmmm, I've typically been relying on the natural digest cycle to do UI changes instead of manually firing an action from ng-change. The goal is to just change a value and then my $scope.canSubmitForm() function will return true after the model changes and $digests.

Comment: Relying on the natural digest cycle is great and you wouldn't be going against it.  You want "when the user changes x, make y visible".  So you could do `ng-change="selectChanged(datarow)"` which maps to some `$scope.selectChanged = function(row){ ... }`.  The `$scope.canSubmitForm` function shouldn't need to be changed and Angular will notice it returns a different value.

Comment: Ah, I understand. Perhaps that's a good way to go to; I was also trying to avoid making a function just for setting a value, but sometimes it's neccessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to resolve the question... Thanks to @eternalmatt for the advice.

I've decided to stick with the data driven model so I can avoid creating a function whose sole purpose is to update data on a higher scope.

Instead, referencing a property in a higher scope works just as well because the lower scope *inherits* from the $parent without explicitly using $parent.

To reiterate my example, above:

```
<div ng-repeat="datarow in datasource">
   <select ng-model="datasource[$index].property" ng-options="option.first_name for option in datarow.options"></select>
</div>
```

My main controller will $digest when it notices a property on one of the objects in the array is updated!